# How to prevent carved text from being distorted while using subdivision modifier

Tags: modifiers

I am attempting to make a set of dice except on one side having black text carved/indented into it. Im using this as a guide

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=sNhN3X3MvD4

All the tutorials I find for dice use basically the same method as 6 sides all have similar patterns. Where I run into an issue is if I use boolean modifier to indent the text then when I add a subdivision modifier later it applies to the entire cube and deforms the indented text. It also deforms it if I attempt to add a boolean modifier after the subdivision modifier.

I am also clueless about how to have my indented text area colored. All my searching yields nothing on these two issues/subjects. If anyone could steer me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

[image: dice]